# Cannot override Linear Gradient on active link

Tags: css, css-transitions, gradient, nav

I have a bootstrap navigation that I have added a simple CSS transition to. When the user hovers over a link it wipes right and changes the background colour to blue. When the user is on the link page `.navactive` is added to the `<li>` class. This is supposed to make the background colour solid blue so the user knows they are on that page. The linear gradient keeps overiding this.

Is there a way to

- override the transition and make it solid
- disable the transition for the link with .navactive in the class

Thanks

```css
.nav li {
  /* Old browsers */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0943A7 50%, #FFFFFF 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: right bottom;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.nav li:hover{
  background-position: left bottom;
}

.navactive {
  background-color: #0943A7 !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: skewX(-18deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-18deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-18deg);
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-faded">
  <div class="container">
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse show" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="nav justify-content-center mx-md-auto">

        <li class="<?php echo ($page == "home" ? "nav-item navactive" : "nav-item")?>">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li class="<?php echo ($page == "page2" ? "nav-item navactive" : "nav-item")?>">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 2</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You need to make the `.navactive` selector more specific for it to override `.nav li`, for example `.nav li.navactive`

Comment: the linear gradient is still overriding it.

Comment: Could you please add the relevant HTML markup to the question. It's hard to diagnose an issue you can't see.

Comment: html has been added

Answer (score 0):

Two things are happening here:

- Css [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) on `.navactive` is lower then `.nav li`
- `background:~~~` is a shorthand for `background-image`, `background-image` overrides `background-color`

Changing the `.navactive` rule to `.nav li.navactive` should take care of the specificity.

Adding `background-image:none;` to  the `.navactive` rule will make sure `background-color` will display.

```css
.nav li {
  /* Old browsers */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0943A7 50%, #FFFFFF 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: right bottom;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.nav li:hover{
  background-position: left bottom;
}

.nav li.navactive {
  background-color: #0943A7 !important;
  background-image:none;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: skewX(-18deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-18deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-18deg);
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-faded">
  <div class="container">
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse show" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="nav justify-content-center mx-md-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li class="page2 nav-item navactive" >
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 2</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

On a side node, you might want to use `font-style:italic` instead of the skewX.